# Symfony 4 not logging in on production mode

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony4, production-environment

I am developing a website in symfony 4.2. After I put it to production server, I modified APP_ENV to prod, and run composer update --no-dev.

After doing this, I can't logging in. I have got no login error. Log files are empty. I have no idea, what I am doing wrong. I also tried to set APP_DEBUG=1 but nothing... It's only reload the login page, whatever I'm doing

Here is my security.yaml:

```
security:
access_decision_manager:
    strategy: affirmative
encoders:
    App\Entity\Account: bcrypt

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    database_users:
        entity: { class: App\Entity\Account, property: username }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true

        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        form_login:
            check_path: security_login
            login_path: security_login
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: home_index
        logout:
                path: security_logout
                target: security_login

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPERIOR: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPERVISOR: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_WORKER: ROLE_USER
```

Login form:

```
<form action="{{ path('security_login') }}" method="post" class="panel-body">
                        {% if error %}
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{ "login.username"|trans }}" type="text" name="_username" id="_username" autofocus />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{ "login.password"|trans }}" type="password" name="_password" id="_password" />
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}" />

                        <input id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block" value="{{ "common.button.login"|trans }}" />
                        <a href="{{ path('security_register') }}" id="register" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block">{{ "common.button.registration"|trans }}</a>
                    </form>
```

SecurityController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="security_login")
 * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function index(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
{
    if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted(["ROLE_USER"])) {
        return new RedirectResponse(
            $this->generateUrl('home_index')
        );
    }

    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error' => $error
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="security_logout")
 */
public function logout()
{
}
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: any logs from apache/nginx?

Comment: Can you run the console without any error ( `php bin/console`)? Check the file permissions. If you switch `APP_ENV` back to dev, does it work?

Comment: Apache log is also empty.
Yes, I can run. If I switch back, it works perfectly.
In framework.yaml, I changed the cookie_secure from auto to false. It is currently working, but I don't think this is "good" solution.

Comment: if `cookie_secure` is set to true, you MUST setup https for your login form to work, else it won't. Do you use https for your production site ?

Comment: Solution was adding cookie name in framework.yaml. This site is on a subdomain and it got an another website's cookie with same name, which is on the parent domain. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check in your DB if your user table contain login and password.